# Finding related tags for searching

Tags: javascript, java, angular, tags

I have implemented a project that uses google place api. What i want to do is to add a find tags button. For example: when the user enters `londra`, then when the user click the button, related tags(maybe londra bridge or capital) will be listed. I use Angular on the front-end and Java on the back-end. Is there any way to implement this property? My code for location api is here

```
 <input type="text" gm-places-autocomplete ng-model="vm.autocomplete" 
 class="form-control"/>
```

Above code make a list and searching is working properly.

Comment: You forgot the code

Comment: I am sorry.I edited it